# Not able to get window.location.search value in HTML - jQueryMobile

Tags: node.js, ejs

My javascript code looks like this

```
var query = window.location.search.replace('?','');
fetchContent(apiUrl + 'service/' + query + '?callback=?', function(data) {
    $('.content').append(data).trigger('create');
});
```

I am using jQueryMobile, nodeJS for services and views. Also, using EJS templates to display data.

The problem is that I am not able to get value for variable *query* in the above code and hence the next following lines form up a parameter *'apiUrl/service/?callback=?'* for fetchContent method which is a wrong URL for my service. The correct parameter for my fetchContent method should be *'apiUrl/service/1234?callback=?'*.

Interesting thing is that this code works fine when I open the link in new tab. URL for the above HTML page in my code is **some.html?1234**. According to this the value in JS code should be 1234 but it is empty.

Comment: What's the actual value (as shown by `console.log()` in the browser) of `window.location.search`?

Comment: `console.log(window.location.search)` is empty